# How/where to declare transaction manager in Spring (WTHOUT BOOT)

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm trying to make the @Transactional annotation work, after a bit of research, I think I have to declare a transaction manager... somewhere? How do I accomplish that? Do I add it to my hibernate.cfg.xlm somehow? Or maybe do I create it at the same time as my EntityManagerFactory?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(entityManagerFactory.getObject()));
    }
```